# Is it possible to install Phpize without php-devel?

Tags: php, pecl, phpize

I need phpize to install an extension on PECL, but inputting the command downloads the extension then tells me that "phpize failed".
After some googling, I noticed that you needed a version of PHP called "php-devel", I don't know if installing this will just replace my installation of php and start using an unstable development version, so i've been trying to install phpize without installing php-devel, but haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: php-devel (or php-dev) isn't unstable version of PHP, it's an package that contains necessary headers and files (like mentioned phpize) for development and compiling of PHP extensions/modules.

Comment: Alright, Thanks hendrik!!!! :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.